# push nested array by php in mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

Hello I have a document in mongodb like this

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56b7451fa91b80e2078b4567"
    },
    "number": "222",
    "value": "hello",
    "name": "James",
    "username": "mahsa",

    "lessons": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "time": "2016-02-11 07:15:00",
            "term": "3"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "time": "2016-02-11 07:45:00",
            "term": "4"

        }
    ]
}
```

I want to push a nested array like this in my document when number=222 and lessons.id=2

```
"marks": [
    {
        "id": "4",
        "value": "10",

    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "value": "9",
    }
]
```

and I want my document change like this

```
 {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "56b7451fa91b80e2078b4567"
        },
        "number": "222",
        "value": "hello",
        "name": "James",
        "username": "mahsa",

        "lessons": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "time": "2016-02-11 07:15:00",
                "term": "3"
                "marks": [
                    {
                     "id": "4",
                      "value": "10",
                     },
                     {
                      "id": "5",
                      "value": "9",

                     }
                 ]
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "time": "2016-02-11 07:45:00",
                "term": "4"

            }
        ]
    }
```

but my code doesn't work
my code is:

```
$myarray=array('$push' =>array("lessons.marks"=>array(array('id'=>'4','value'=>'10'),
   array('id'=>'5','value'=>'9') )));
$where=array('number'=>"222",'lessons.id'=>'2');
$this->collection->update($where,$myarray);
```

What's the problem?
How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

## Mongo nested update in: array of arrays

Just make a few changes in your PHP code:

```
$collectionObj->update(
array('number'=>'222','lessons.id'=>'2'),
array('$set'=>array(
'lessons.$.marks'=> array(
    array('id'=>'4','value'=>'10'),
    array('id'=>'5','value'=>'9')
))));
```

In **lessons.$.marks** '$' specify the index of the array in context..
Hope this works..

Comment: excus me @Sahil Gulati , if I want change my condition to number=222 and lessons.id=2 and lessons.term=3 , It isn't Ok as $criteria,why? array('number'=>'222','lessons.id'=>'2','lessons.term'=>'3')

Comment: @sahar21 I have tested that particular document on my end and It worked. Please use this $collectionObj->find( array('number'=>'222','lessons.id'=>'2','lessons.term'=>'3'));     Is this giving you results from mongo?

Comment: Yes ,It works, but when lessons.id=2 not check the lessons.term and when lessons.term=3 not check the lessons.id and  update is wrong ,It works as regular or !

Comment: Ofcourse,I want to push mark array only when my variables are  exactly this: array('number'=>'222','lessons.id'=>'2','lessons.term'=>'3') after "id": "2",
                "time": "2016-02-11 07:15:00",
                "term": "3" ,  but  when I use array('number'=>'222','lessons.id'=>'2','lessons.term'=>'4') or array('number'=>'222','lessons.id'=>'3','lessons.term'=>'3') , has a similar result .

Comment: @sahar21 I got your problem and I don't think that this can be possible through Mongo operators. We can't rely completely on mongodb for all our needed options. The only option i am left with is to manipulate the whole document's lessons field and update with $set operator... I tried hard but thats all what i am left with.